# PHP Login only working if Remember Me box is checked. If not checked, session is not being set.

Tags: php, session, cookies

For some reason my login system is only working if my remember me box is checked. If it is not checked it just redirects back to the login page and does not log the user in. My code on the login page is as follows:

```
<?php

require 'connection.php';
require 'function.php';

session_name('sessionlogin');

session_set_cookie_params(2*7*24*60*60);

session_start();

if($_SESSION['id'] && !isset($_COOKIE['Remembercookie']) && !$_SESSION['Remembercheck'])
{

    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();

}


if(isset($_GET['logoff']))
{
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();

    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
?>

Login:<br>
            <form name="login" action="includes/login.php" method="post">
                Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br>
                Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br>
                <input name="Remembercheck" id="Remembercheck" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1" />
                <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit"/><br><br><br>
            </form>
```

And this is login.php:

```
<?php 

require 'connection.php';
require 'function.php';
require 'salt.php';

session_name('sessionlogin');
session_start();

if($_POST['submit']=='Login')
{
    $err = array();

    if(!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password'])
        $err[] = 'All the fields must be filled in!';

    if(!count($err))
    {
        $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $_POST['password'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $_POST['Remembercheck'] = (int)$_POST['Remembercheck'];

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,usr, FROM table WHERE usr='{$_POST['username']}' AND pass='{$_POST['password']}'"));

        if($row['usr'])
        {

            $_SESSION['usr']=$row['usr'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['Remembercheck'] = $_POST['Remembercheck'];


            setcookie('Remembercookie',$_POST['Remembercheck']);
        }
        else $err[]='Wrong username and/or password!';
    }

    if($err)
        $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);

    echo header("Location: ../index.php");
    exit;
}
```

There is password hashing and some more stuff involved but i stripped all of that out to simplify the question and make it relevant to this specific problem. Please help!

Comment: Can you please add your code out of the `index.php`?

Answer (score 0):

For your Login.php file try this:

```
<?php 

require 'connection.php';
require 'function.php';
require 'salt.php';

// uncomment if you create a connection to your mysql database like this:
// $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
// global $c;

if($_POST['submit']=='Login')
{
    $err = array();

    if(!isset($_POST['username']) || !isset($_POST['password']))
    {
        $err[] = 'All the fields must be filled in!';
    }
    else
    {
        $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $rcheck = (int)$_POST['Remembercheck'];

    $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE usr='$user' AND pass='$pass'", $c); // i dont know how your are connecting to your database, but you may need to add your $c in your query
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
    $num = mysql_num_rows($q);

    if($q != 1) //should only return 1 user
    {
        // Error
    }
    else
    {
        session_name('sessionlogin'); //start your session after the users credentials match
        session_start();

        $_SESSION['usr']= $row['usr'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['Remembercheck'] = $rcheck;

        setcookie('Remembercookie',$rcheck);

        header("Location: ../index.php");
    }
    else
    {
    $err[]='Wrong username and/or password!';
    }
}

if($err)
$_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);

exit;
}
```

Your code seems a bit messy, and you should really start using mysqli, as mysql is deprecated, or going that way. A login code that I myself use frequently, without fail is this, however it does not have the remember me, but that wont make a difference:

```
    <?php

    include "mysqli.php";
    global $db; // i use the OOP (object oriented programming) method for connecting to the database.

include "func.php";

// set the variables
$username = $db->real_escape_string(strtolower($_POST['user'])); // i use strtolower to avoid case-sensitive errors, it lowers the strength of passwords so isnt fully recommended
$password = $db->real_escape_string(strtolower($_POST['pass']));
$epassword = md5($password); // hashing the password adds a level of security, however not as much anymore as it can be brute forced. you also need to be aware that your password field in your database must contain the hashed password

$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE (username = '$username') AND (password = '$epassword')");
$nr = $sql->num_rows;

if( $nr != 1 )
{
    echo "<font color='red'>LOGIN ERROR</font><br />";
    $q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username'");
    $q_nr = $q->num_rows;
    if( $q_nr != 1 )
    {
        echo "<font color='red'>Username does not exist</font><br />";
        echo "<a href='login.php> > Back </a>";
            exit;
    }
    else
    {
        $q1 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE (username = '$username') AND (password = '$epassword')");
        $q1_nr = $q1->num_rows;
        if ( $q1_nr != 1 )
        {
            echo "<font color='red'>Password does not match account</font><br />";
            echo "<a href='login.php> > Back </a>";
            exit;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    $nar = $sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $nar['uid'];

    header("location:index.php");
}

?>
```